# continuous incrementing number for each apply iOS

Tags: ios, numbers, parse-platform, increment, continuous

I am developing with Parse.com as my back-end a simple app. 
As part of it there is an apply screen, wherein customers fill in the information for the suppliers (like, which part for which machinery etc). Than I want to save this details in the backend. But i want to save each apply with a continuous incrementing number (ApplyNumber), starting at apply 1,2,3 etc..

How can I do this, I read a lot at the Parse.com docs, posted at the forum, no replies, maybe its better to implement a code programatically.

What I have now is:

```
PFObject *apply = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Applys"];

        [apply setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"Applier"];

        apply[@"describtion1"] = descritiption1;
        apply[@"describtion2"] = description2;


        [apply incrementKey:@"ApplyNumber"];

        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        onderdeelAanvraag[@"Datum"] =date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `incrementKey` method will increment a value on a single object, so you could use this as long as you have a single shared object to store the counter on.

For example, if you wanted the numbers to start at 1 for each `Supplier`, then on the `Supplier` object you could have an `ApplyNumber` property. You would need to call `incrementKey` and in the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` method you could then use the (now updated) value of `ApplyNumber` to set a property on the `Applys` class you create.

If you're wanting a global number, you will need to create a global object for this. To make things quicker I would pre-create a single row in a new `GlobalSettings` class and configure the `objectId` as part of your app settings so you can quickly load and adjust settings like your `ApplyNumber` counter.

NOTE: I am curious why you want an auto-increasing number, is it just coming from a SQL background and you are used to it, or does it have some value to your app/users? You could achieve this by just doing a `countObjects` query for any with a lesser created date/time.

Comment: Timothy, thanks for your answer. But I could not really understand how you meant to code that...I am a beginner...and I followed a course at teamtreehouse.com where they used Parse.com. I just want to create a column in the back end, which is a continuous incrementing number. 

For the globalsettings method you said, I just get one global number, which I dont want. I want that each `apply` has is own number beginning from 1 (apply, applynumber:1 ; apply, applynumber:2 ...really that simple)

Comment: @Enzo yes, to keep track of what number you are up to you will need to store it somewhere, thus my suggestion of a global. What you are asking for is not something that is generally done in NoSQL database systems like Parse, so you need to work around it